# Azure AD How to assign all groups of an existing user to a new user?

Tags: azure, shell, azure-active-directory

Hallo i have a users in Azure AD with is member of 50 groupps and i want an new user to be member of same 50 groups is there any way to add new user to all those 50 groups withouts doing one by one?

so far no idea i can only add them one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [AzureAD powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) and by using the below cmdlet.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId "the current user object number you want to copy from" |foreach { Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $_.ObjectId -RefObjectId " the new user object number here" }
```

I have tested this and it is working fine.